# Cannot cast array data... matplotlib and python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, charts

I am trying to make a 3d line chart with matplotlib in python. The data set is taken from a measuring station with different sensors. Now i have the code pretty much as i want it, but every time i try to run it it shows this problem:

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'

My code so far:

```
import csv
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

depth = {
    1 : 11, 2 : 35, 3 : -1, 4 : 11, #position of graphs in cm
}
class SetXYZ:
    def __init__(self, datalist, NameNum): #datalist: list with data, NameNum: number of variable
        self.NameNum = NameNum
        self.datalist = datalist
        self.Name = datalist[0][NameNum]
        self.length = datalist

    def X(self): #Creates list with X Variables
        Xlist = []
        for element in self.datalist:
            Xlist.append(element[0])
        Xlist.pop(0)
        return Xlist

    def Y(self): #Creates list with Y Variables
        Ylist = []
        for element in self.datalist:
            Ylist.append(element[self.NameNum])
        Ylist.pop(0)
        return Ylist

    def Z(self): #list with Z variables
        Zlist = []
        for element in datalist: #Z is the same for every point on one graph
            Zlist.append(depth[self.NameNum-1])
        Zlist.pop(0)
        return Zlist


def csv_to_list(filename): #returns the file as list
    with open(filename, 'rb') as data:
        data = csv.reader(data, delimiter=';')
        datalist = list(data)
        return datalist


filename = "     " #Filename

datalist = csv_to_list(filename)

Graph1 = SetXYZ(datalist, 1)  #creates the graphs
Graph2 = SetXYZ(datalist, 2)

#plots a graph, more or less to test
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(Graph1.X(), Graph1.Y(), Graph1.Z())

plt.show()
```

a file looks like this:

Time; sensor 1; sensor 2; sensor 3; sensor4

41940.6791666667;16;19.96;4.1;11.52

41940.67986;15.9;20.51;4.07;11.4

41940.67986;15.9;20.53;4.07;11.41

The full error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 338, in resizeEvent
    self.draw()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 148, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 461, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1079, in draw
    func(*args)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 254, in draw
    for col in self.collections]

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py", line 413, in do_3d_projection
    vxs, vys, vzs, vis = proj3d.proj_transform_clip(xs, ys, zs, renderer.M)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\proj3d.py", line 208, in proj_transform_clip

    return proj_transform_vec_clip(vec, M)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\proj3d.py", line 165, in proj_transform_vec_clip

    vecw = np.dot(M, vec)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

When it is finished there can be up to 30 sensors and several thousand times.

Is there a workaround to this, or what am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: always present the stack trace (i.e. the full error) if the code you're posting is not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Moreover, it would help if you can post an extract of `datalist`

Comment: I have edited the full error in. And datalist is made from filename by a file similar to the example in my post.

Comment: in the definition of `Z()` in the class `SetXYZ` I had to change `self.NameNum-1` into `self.NameNum` as key value of `depth`, and then with the above example file no exception is thrown. Does the code work if you comment out the plotting part of the script? From the stack trace we can't tell which line in your code triggered the error, but it looks like it could be in the plotting part.

Comment: I forgot to delete the -1. and it works fine without the plotting part. Can it be a bug in matplotlib?

Comment: @DasBanzai - Most likely, you have an array of strings as your input to your plotting functions.  It looks like you're not doing a float conversion anywhere.  Either cast things to floats/ints or perhaps use `np.loadtxt` or a similar function rather than the builtin `csv` library.

Comment: The key is `Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32')`  It is saying that it can to cast from 64bit float to a fixed length 32 character string.  The problem is on your input.